# Arrow keys not working correctly in remote vi

Tags: ssh, vi

I'm on a linux box connected with ssh to another linux box.
When editing a file with vi, arrow keys work in default mode, but when I switch to edit mode ('a' or 'i') arrow keys output letters (like B). That makes me crazy.
Any idea on how to fix that?

TIA

greg

Comment: Some details might help a lot to generate better/more answers. For example: What are your terminal settings? What is in $TERM? What SSH client are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be probably default vi thats built into bash. Did you try install vim "apt-get install vim" on Ubuntu/Debian?

Comment: Nice! I didn't know there was such a thing. Running "vi" was giving me the "VIM improved" message... installing the real VIM package did the trick. Thanks @Sai !